# 24 hours Radar chart in amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, json, charts, amcharts, radar-chart

I would like to create a [Radar Chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/radar-with-date-axis/). which satisfy below points in Amcharts

- The date should be changed to duration format eg. **Yaxis**: Jan Feb  to 1 2 ..24
- Show **Xasix** data in a format of startTiming and endTiming

  [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajrs/wLu3x98r/16/)

```js
 {
        Shift: "Morning",
        startTime1: "9:00",
        endTime1: "17:00"
    },
   
    {
        Shift: "Afternoon",
        startTime2: "13:30",
        endTime2: "4:00"
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to give data as multiple of 60  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajrs/yfc4m5Ld/16/)

### start time => 1*60 = 60

### end time => 10* 60 = 600

```
{
    duration: "One",
    startTime1: 60,
    endtime1: 600
 }
```